# Getting VPN to work from Virtual PC

Tags: vpn, vmware-workstation

Setup: Host is running Windows7. Virtual PC is a Windows Server 2008 running under VMWare workstation 6.5.

From the Host I have a VPN to e.g. TFS and other resources. From the VPC I need to connect to e.g. a SQL server via the VPN.

My problem is, that I cannot get a connection from the VPC. If I'm sitting on the corporate network, all is working fine (but then I don't have the VPN). From home - where the VPN is required - it does not work.

I have two network adapters defined/configued. One as BRIDGED and one as Host Only. IF I change the one being BRIDTED to NATS I have no connectivity at all from the VPC.

I have no problems connecting from my host to the VPC.

Comment: A little updated information which may or may not be of interest. I added the Host DSN to the network settings of the VM. This actually allowed to to open the VPN from within the VM and hence connect to some of the required resources. I'm not quite there yet, but getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a long shot, but is the guest OS configured with a static IP? When you use NAT on a virtual adapter, the guest needs to acquire its address via DHCP (the host becomes the DHCP server). That would explain why you lose all network connectivity when switching to NAT.

If you do have a static IP on the guest, try switching it to acquire its address automatically, then use NAT on the virtual adapter. Once this is configured, when you connect the host to the VPN, the guest should have access to it as well.